# Magento 2 Some products don't show price on frontend due to the product is not Salable?

Tags: price, magento2.2.2

Some of my products don't show prices on frontend. And when I diagnose the issue, I found this file,

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php
```

And if I commented out the line 68, the Prices are displaying.

```
if (!$this->salableResolver->isSalable($this->getSaleableItem())) {
   // return '';
}
```

So this means that Magento doesn't think my products are saleable? or what was wrong?

Comment: Can you check the inventory settings of your products where prices are not showing?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?